# I made an code with command append, to compare two tensors with pytorch. What's wrong with it?

Tags: loops, for-loop, pytorch

```
xxx=torch.tensor([True,True,False,True])
xxxz=torch.tensor([True,False,False,True])

def zzz():
  asdf=[]
  for i in range(4):
    if xxx[i] == xxxz[i] and xxx[i] == True:
      asdf.append(i)
      return asdf

zzz()
```

What I expected was: [0,3].

But the result was : [0]. I don't get what's wrong with it. Did I use append wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return statement is inside `for` and `if`. Pull it outside at the level of function definition

```
def zzz():
  asdf=[]
  for i in range(4):
    if xxx[i] == xxxz[i] and xxx[i] == True:
      asdf.append(i)
      # return asdf # NOPE
  return asdf # THIS
```

Earlier, your function was returning just after encountering 0. That's why 3 was missing.